# How to maintain Immutable nature of a class referencing Mutable Objects?

Tags: java, immutability

I am well aware of rules to make a class Immutable. But Consider a situation where my class A which compose class B. Class B is in external jar and Class B again compose of C and D i.e.

```
class A{
  B b;
}
// External library
class B{
  C c;
  D d;
}
class C{
}
class D{
}
```

How can I make class A Immutable if I can't modify classes in External lib? If classes in External lib were modifiable, I could have implement cloneable but this is not possible since I can't modify them.

Comment: It's obvious: Don't give anyone outside class A access to mutable references.   Don't allow A to change its references to B, C, or D.

Comment: can you please explain it with an example code?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Does client code need access to `b`? - ie is there a `public B getB()` method?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes it has

Comment: @AnkitPandoh If client code has and needs access to the instance of `B` via `getB`, the client code can mutate `B`. You should not expose `B` but rather expose a limited interface with methods the client code need.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a defensive copy of the mutable instance:

```
class A {

    private final B b;

    public A(B b) {
        // Create a defensive copy of b
        this.b = new B(b);
    }
}
```

If `B` does not provide a copy constructor like this, you will need to implement defensive copying for `B` on your own.

If you don't do this, I can pass an instance of `B` to `A`, but also keep that instance of `B` to myself and mutate it later on at my own will.

Comment: In this case we should not be providing any getters (getB()). Since I can again mutate C and D if I have access to getter method by calling getB().getC() (assuming B has getter of C). Is this correct understanding?

Comment: @AnkitPandoh Yes, keep it private. If you expose instances of `B`, they can be modified externally.

Answer (score 0):

Class A should not allow access to any mutable references.

Here's what your class example would look like:

```
class A {

  private final B b;

  public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  // no public access to B reference that's final.  No changing it from the outside.  A is immutable.
}
```

Classes B, C, and D are from a library.  If you give A a mutable reference and allow the rest of the code to change the state of B or its C and D children there's nothing to be done about that.  But if you construct B properly and entrust it to A, then no one else will be able to alter its state.

Comment: I can pass an instance of `B` to `A` and keep that instance of `B`. I can later on mutate that instance of `B`.

Comment: Create an instance that cannot be used by anyone else.  You can do that, but it spoils the effect you are aiming for.  It's your code - do what needs to be done.

Comment: My point is, `A` as per code your posted can be mutated even if it does not allow access to any mutable references. You answer to that is simply "don't do it" which is, in my opinion, quite weak.
We should consider two actors here - the OP which wants to make `A` truly immutable. And maleficent Dev which wants to mutate `A`. With this answer, Dev will be able to harm.

Comment: Weak, indeed.  Your point about a copy constructor for B and a defensive copy are genuinely good.  Worthwhile contributions.